# How to fetch direct url from image

Tags: php

I am getting the image links where my image is there by using reverse image search provided by google but now we want the exact path of that page  where my particular image is situated like http://www.indiamart.com/lelijiye-bengaluru/maroon-color-desginer-saree.html page

Answer (score 0):

Direct linking is the use of a particular image or multimedia file on another website by linking directly to it on another web host's server. (I use Photobucket)

For example, if you want to post an image on another forum, a direct linking URL (found on the edit image page) can be used to display that image via the PBase server on another website or forum.

An easy way to find the direct linking URL for your images is to go to the edit image page and see the 'direct linking URL' at the top right of the screen.

Comment: how to get edit image page please tell me i am a beginer

Comment: Or Any one can help me ?